# Fetch buddy press user avtar by id /email /username

Tags: buddypress, wordpress

I am creating a system in which, i am able to fetch user_id,user_email but unable to fetch user avatar(profile picture).

unable to find how user_image or group_image are stored in data base and how can i fetch.(any query)

i have to fetch image of buddy press user avatar by user_id. if anyone have any solution please post answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try default functionality of word press for get avatar by user ID:

```
echo get_avatar( $userID, 32 );
```

I have tried it and it display buddy press user avatar by user ID.

[Get Avatar in word press](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)

Comment: i am creating a service that is( code ) out side  my wordpress files get_avatar() function i can not access. i have  access to database only